# Steam in Juno- how to install

Tags: applications, appcenter, release-juno, steam

In the app center, there are two choices for steam: 1. steam with the default cog icon, and steam installer with the regular steam icon. There's also the deb file you can download from the Steam website. My question is which of these methods is the best way to install steam in Juno?
I've already had to reinstall the OS because I did not choose wisely. Which one do you all recommend?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same question!

I installed STEAM instead of STEAM Installer.
It worked just fine, logged in, installed games, selected steam play + proton and running games, really happy about it :)

Hope it works for u too